# Replace value from one column with a value from another columns

Tags: postgresql

```
|Name    | FamilyName |
+--------+------------+
Penelopa | Crow       |
Mandarin | Overflow   |
```

I want to read Penelopa from "Name" and replace Crow value from "FamilyName" with Penelopa in a single query.

I do know that the Name I'm interested to use would be Penelopa as I do something like, and it exist.

```
SELECT "Name" FROM MyTable WHERE "Name" = 'Penelopa';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a basic update statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET "FamilyName" = "Name"
WHERE "Name" = 'Penelopa' AND "FamilyName" = 'Crow'
```

To be sure that we are not replacing all family names with the name penelopa, but only the one for familyname Crow, I've included this condition in the `WHERE` statement.

One more thing to note would be that creating tables and columns with quotation marks `"` only makes it harder to code so I would avoid that.

---

To see your changes immediately without typing another query, you might add `RETURNING *` clause at the end of `UPDATE` query like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET "FamilyName" = "Name"
WHERE "Name" = 'Penelopa' AND "FamilyName" = 'Crow'
RETURNING *
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL script can do what do the update you want to do (replace table by your table name):

```
update table set FamilyName=Name where Name='Penelopa';
```